# Relative homology $H_n(S^2,S^0)$, or other examples

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've been reading Hatcher and think I understand the idea of relative homology, but he only provides two (fairly trivial) examples, homology relative to a point computing $H(S^n)$ using $D^n$s. My practice final has the question

Compute the relative homology groups $H_n(S^2,S^0)$.

It would be helpful if somebody could show me how to do this. My biggest problem is that I don't understand how $S^0$ is a subspace of $S^2$.
I'd also love to see any other examples of relative homology computations. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S^0 \subset S^2$ be two antipodal points marked on $S^2$. One can use the relative homology long exact sequence for $(S^2, S^0)$ which is of the form

$$\cdots \to {H_i}(S^0) \to {H_i}(S^2) \to {H_i}(S^2, S^0) \to H_{i-1}(S^0) \to H_{i-1}(S^2) \to \cdots$$

If $i \geq 2$ then $H_i(S^0) = H_{i-1}(S^0) = 0$, so the middle map is an isomorphism, yielding $H_i(S^2, S^0) = H_i(S^2)$. If $i = 1$, the last two terms are $H_0(S^0) = \Bbb Z^2$ and $H_0(S^2) = \Bbb Z$ and the map $\Bbb Z^2 \to \Bbb Z$ is surjective since the inclusion $S^0 \to S^2$ is surjective on path components. Therefore the exact sequence boils down to

$$0 \to H_1(S^2, S^0) \to \Bbb Z^2 \to \Bbb Z \to 0$$

which implies $H_1(S^2, S^0) = \Bbb Z$. Moreover since $H_0(S^0) \to H_0(S^2)$ is surjective, it's cokernel $H_0(S^2, S^0) = 0$. So $H_i(S^2, S^0) = \Bbb Z$ if $i = 1, 2$ and zero otherwise.

However, a better way would be to just note that $(S^2, S^0)$ is a CW-pair and thus has homotopy extension property, which implies $H_i(S^2, S^0) \cong \tilde{H_i}(S^2/S^0) \cong \tilde{H_i}(S^2 \vee S^1)$ which is $\Bbb Z$ if $i = 1, 2$ and trivial otherwise (note that this is reduced homology, and $S^2 \vee S^1$ is connected, so there's nothing in degree $0$).

Comment: This is really old, but I feel like I should ask because both yours and Ayman's answer give the same answer here: $\tilde{H}_1(S^2 \vee S^1)$ is not trivial, but equal to $\mathbb{Z}$, right? I'm not an expert on this, but wedge sums of spaces turn into direct sums of reduced homologies, so this should be right. I felt this should be noted for future confused mathpeople.

Comment: @Lukas Whoa, thanks for pointing this out, clearly what I wrote is total garbage! Let me fix it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The usual embedding of $S^{n-1}$ in $S^n$ is as the equatorial sphere; repeating that gives an embedding $S^0 \to S^2$. You can take any two distinct points in $S^2$ for the embedding here, though. The long exact sequence in homology is given by:

$$\cdots \tilde H_*(S^0) \to \tilde H_*(S^2) \to \tilde H_*(S^2, S^0) \to \tilde H_{*-1}(S^0) \to \cdots$$
Since $S^2$ and $S^0$ conveniently carry no homology in adjacent dimensions, this sequence determines $\tilde H_*(S^2, S^0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that doesn't use the long exact sequence for homology.

From the realization of $S^2$ as a CW complex, we see that $S^0$ is identified with two antipodal points in $S^2$.

Since $H_i(S^2, S^0) \cong \tilde H_i(S^2 / S^0)$ and $S^2 / S^0$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$, we see that $H_i(S^2, S^0) \cong \mathbb Z$ for $i = 2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was under the impression that $H_i(S^2,S^0) \cong H_i(S^2/S^0)$ iff there was a deformation retract. Why can we use this here? Also, why is $S^2/S^0$ homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$?

Comment: $S^2/S^0$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$ with a 1-cell attached, with one endpoint pasted to the south pole, and another endpoint pasted to the north pole. And that in turn is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$

Comment: Perfect. Really appreciate all the answers.